# How to determine which table a column belongs to in an SQL Statement given metadata information and parse tree from SQL grammar?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, antlr4

I have a SQL statement, a parse tree of the statement based on T-SQL grammar, and a catalog information that contains a mapping between each table and its columns. Since two tables can have the same column name, how can I differentiate which table a column belongs to? Example shown below.

**Product**:

```
ID uniqueidentifier
Category nvarchar(500)
Manufacturer nvarchar(500)
```

**Invoice**:

```
ID uniqueidentifier
Category nvarchar(500)
InvoiceTo nvarchar(100)
ProductID uniqueidentifier
```

Query:

```
SELECT P.ID, CATEGORY, MANUFACTURER
FROM PRODUCT P
WHERE ID IN (SELECT PRODUCTID FROM INVOICE WHERE CATEGORY = 'TEST')
```

As you can see, there are two category columns here, one in `Product` and one in `Invoice`. I can walk the parse tree and list all columns and tables. I can also look up the above mapping to see which table the column belongs to. But for `Category` column, I cannot resolve its table.

**Expected**:

Tables:

```
Product  
Invoice
```

Columns:

```
Product.ID   
Product.Category  
Product.Manufacturer  
Invoice.ProductID  
Invoice.Category
```

I am using ANTLR to generate the parser code. Then I use the Listener approach to hook to the subtrees I am interested in which are `table_name` and `column_name`.

Here is the grammar file: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/tsql

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
This is what my Listener class looks like:

```cs
  class TSqlNameListener : TSqlParserBaseListener {
        public HashSet<string> Tables { get; set; }
        public List<string> Columns { get; set; }

        public TSqlNameListener() {
            Tables = new HashSet<string>();
            Columns = new List<string>();
        }

        public override void EnterTable_name([NotNull] TSqlParser.Table_nameContext context) {
            Tables.Add(context.GetText());
            base.EnterTable_name(context);
        }

        public override void EnterFull_column_name([NotNull] TSqlParser.Full_column_nameContext context) {
            Columns.Add(context.GetText());
            base.EnterFull_column_name(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show how are you getting the output in the ANTLR

Answer (score 3):

Create a symbol table from your parse tree. This is a hierarchical view of your input, which allows to determine the context for a given symbol. In such a symbol table you would have a node, say, `SelectSymbol` which represents a `SELECT` command. This node contains children for each part of that query, including a `WhereSymbol` node for the `WHERE` clause. I think you see the pattern.

With this table you can now do a lookup, starting from the position of your column in the input. Once found, you then walk up the parent chain to find the context for the column (here the sub select), which contains the table + alias you want.

An example for how to use a listener to create a symbol table can be found in my [antlr4-vscode extension code](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/DetailsListener.ts#L29). This listener fills a symbol table from an ANTLR4 grammar.

**Note:** this approach is only possible if your input is syntactically correct (i.e. can be parsed). If that's not (always) the case (e.g. in an editor) you need a different approach, which requires more work.

Comment: Symbol table is a good idea. However, I am struggling to define what is the scope of a rule (for example select). For a C-like programming language, we have class scope, function scope, block scope, and so on. But for SQL statement like Select, how do you determine the scope?
Here is the parse tree for the above sql: https://imgur.com/a/I6L7QTq

Comment: @khalidcawl Column references without an explicit table or table alias are associated with the innermost containing data source that has that column. Since `full_column_name` `CATEGORY` doesn't have an associated `table_name` you need to go up the parse tree to the `query_specification` and then walk the list of `table_sources` in the `FROM` clause to determine if there is an unambiguous `table_source` for the `simple_id`. If there is no `table_source` containing the `simple_id` then proceed up the tree to the next `query_specification` and repeat the search. And so on.

Comment: About the scope: an SQL command is strictly defined by its syntax. There's no ambiquity. The symbol table can be filled by opening a new scope on a top level keyword (like `SELECT`) and adding all the elements to it that appear in the parse tree below that `SELECT`. However, if you just want to get that table and have no other need to examine the parse tree then a simple walk like suggested by @HABO is sufficient.